# Click and object, then click the ground, make object move to that position

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi there I'd like to be able to click on an object then click a position on a plane and would like my object to lerp to that mouse clicked position. The problem is doing this for more than one object becomes tricky. Anybody got any ideas? so far I have followed the tutorial on Coroutines on unity3D's website under the advanced scripting tutorials. here is the code:

attached to the game object:

```
private Vector3 target;
public float smoothing = 7f;

public Vector3 Target
{
    get{return target;}
    set
    {
        target = value;
        StopCoroutine("Movement");
        StartCoroutine("Movement",target);
    }
}
IEnumerator Movement(Vector3 target)
{
    while (Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target) > 0.05f) 
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target, smoothing* Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

attached to the plane:

```
public propertiesandcoroutines coroutinescript;
private float Deltapos = 0.5f;
private GameObject collobj;

public void OnMouseDown()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit);

    if (hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject) 
    {
        coroutinescript.Target = new Vector3( hit.point.x,hit.point.y + Deltapos,hit.point.z);
    }
}
```

this code works perfectly for one game object. how can I change this to work for a game object that I click on?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: take a look https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/navigation it's part of your task

Comment: @bish I've edited my post. the code works perfectly for one game object. however I want to be able to click an object (sorta like select it) then click on a position on my plane to move it. thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a couple of lines to each script to get the result you want.

To the script attached to your moveable GameObjects

```
//This is the same type as the script attached to your plane. Rename it
//to whatever it's actually called (I've just called it PlaneScript). Also
//drag the plane into this field for each of the moveable GameObjects in the inspector

public PlaneScript planeScript;

//Paste this method anywhere inside the script attached to the GameObjects

void OnMouseUpAsButton () {
    planeScript.SetObjectToMove(this);
}
```

Now, in the script attached to your plane, add the following

```
public void SetObjectToMove (propertiesandcoroutines script) {
    coroutinescript = script;
}
```

**How it works**
Basically, what we're doing here is when one of your GameObjects are clicked, we reassign the **"coroutinescript"** variable in the script attached to the plane.
So, when the plane is clicked, the last GameObject that was clicked on before clicking the plane is moved.

Comment: Words cannot really express..... Thank you so much. my university project will go well now. thanks and god bless you

Comment: what if my  game objects are instantiated? how would I assign plane to each game object? currently im using resource.load to load my prefabs from the resource folder.

Comment: Use GameObject.Find & GetComponent to get the instance of the PlaneScript

Comment: hi I have different placeholders that I'd like to move my objects to. Any idea how I can achieve this? The idea is that the player clicks the cube and moves it to the placeholder,and so on. I know I can attach the plane script to a prefab called placeholder.. But am still confused how to implement it.